# Как динамически запросить время у администратора перед отправкой сообщения в телеграм-группу с использованием aiogram 3.X?

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Я работаю над функцией для телеграм-бота на базе aiogram, которая позволяет администраторам группы отправлять автоматизированные уведомления участникам о предстоящих мероприятиях. Моя текущая задача - запросить у администратора, который активирует команду, точное время события через ЛС, и только после этого отправить итоговое сообщение в группу с указанным временем. Ниже приведен мой текущий код:

```
async def is_user_admin(chat_id: int, user_id: int) -> bool:
   try:
       member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
       # Проверяем, является ли участник создателем группы или администратором
       return member.status in ["administrator", "creator"]
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)  # Логирование ошибки для отладки
       return False
  

@dp.message(Command('YF'),message_is_group)
async def catalog(message: Message):
   allowed_group_id = -*** #id группы 
   if message.chat.type == ChatType.SUPERGROUP and message.chat.id == allowed_group_id:
       if await is_user_admin(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id):
           # Инициализация базы данных и запросы к ней...
           # Формирование и отправка сообщения...
       else:
           await message.answer('Эта команда доступна только администраторам и создателю группы.')
   else:
       await message.answer('Эта команда не доступна в данном чате.')
```

Как мне модифицировать этот код, чтобы после активации команды бот отправлял запрос в ЛС администратору с просьбой указать время, и только после получения ответа формировал и отправлял сообщение в группу с этим временем?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и рекомендации по реализации этой функции.